# Match variable with several arrays

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Lets say I have random $variable and three arrays:

```
$array1 = ("one", "two", "three");
$array2 = ("four", "five", "six");
$array3 = ("seven", "eight", "nine");
```

How to do this:

```
if $variable is in $array1
echo "in array one";
elseif $variable is $array2
echo "in array two";
elseif $variable is in $array3
echo "in array three";
else
echo "variable isnt in any of arrays";
```

I hope you got the point, I would really appreciate any help, I thinking about forearching items in array one by one and then preg_matching them.. But i cant figure out how to do it with more than one array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `in_array`, see manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
  if (in_array($variable, $array1))
   echo "in array one";
  else if (in_array($variable, $array2))
    echo "in array two";
  else if (in_array($variable, $array3))
    echo "in array three";
  else
    echo "variable isnt in any of arrays";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in_array()` function. [[Doc](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php)]

Your code would look like:

```
if (in_array ($variable, $array1)) {
 echo "in array 1";
} else if(in_array ($variable, $array2)) {
 echo "in array 2";
} [...] else {
 echo "isnt in any";
}
```

Comment: Did not now this function before, too (;